# Reactjs force DOM update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations

I am trying to get css animations going for the height of an element via react.

CSS animations for height are hard as they require static heights.

To animate a collapse (height from x to 0) I set the height of the element to a static height (using scrollHeight) then set the height to 0 right after, and vice versa for an expand (height from 0 to x).

Unfortunately this only works sometimes. I think react is detecting that these two events are happening quickly on the same prop and only propagating the latest to the DOM which breaks my animation.

**Is there a way to force react to propagate both changes to the DOM?**

Code (prob not terribly interesting):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.open !== this.props.open){
        if(nextProps.open){
            this.setState({height:0, animating: true});
        }
        else{
            this.setState({height:this.refs.body.scrollHeight, animating: true});
        }
    }
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevProps.open !== this.props.open){
        if(prevProps.open && !this.props.open){
            this.setState({height: '0'});
        }
        else{
            this.setState({height: this.refs.body.scrollHeight});
        }
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.setState({animating:false});
        }.bind(this), this.props.animationTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.forceUpdate()` will flush your changes directly to the DOM.

Comment: The reason your setup does not work as expected is because a `setState()` inside `componentWillReceiveProps` does not trigger re-render, as [explained in react component lifecycle docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops). `this.forceUpdate()` as mentioned by @limelights does..

Comment: I tried using `this.forceUpdate()` but no luck. It still appears to skip rendering the first height to the DOM. I think React propagates to the DOM out of band from the render, and only renders the latest changes to the DOM. (eg if you have made two changes in really quick succession to the vDOM, it may only perform one update to the actual DOM)